# Bad mask /30 for address in Router Cisco (Packet Tracer)

Tags: cisco

```
HQ>enable

Password: 

HQ#config terminal

Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.

HQ(config)#int s0/0

HQ(config-if)#ip add 209.165.201.3 255.255.255.252

Bad mask /30 for address 209.165.201.3

HQ(config-if)#
```

How can I change?

Comment: 209.165.201.3 it's a broadcast IP for 209.165.201.3/30 (Network IP is .0 first usable IP is .1 second usable ip is .2 and .3 is the broadcast IP) what network and IP do you have on the other end of the cable?

Answer (score 3):

Because `209.165.201.3` is the last IP address in the network `209.165.201.0/30` and thus is the broadcast address, it is not available for use as a host inside the network.

Answer (score 0):

With a 255.255.255.252 subnet mask, the ip address you are specifying is the broadcast address

```
BROADCAST=209.165.201.3
NETWORK=209.165.201.0
```

You will only be able to use 209.165.201.1 or 209.165.201.2 as an IP address.